# Using __contains__ on a list of custom class objects

Tags: python

I have a simple class defined like this:

```
class User(object):
    def __init__(self, id=None, name=None):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name

    def __contains__(self, item):
        return item == self.id
```

Using this class, I can do simple checks of single instances of the class like so:

```
>>> user1 = User(1, 'name_1')
>>> 1 in user1
True
>>> 2 in user1
False
```

This is working as expected.

How can I check if a value is in a list of `User` objects though? It always seems to return False.

Example:

```
from random import randint
from pprint import pprint
users = [User(x, 'name_{}'.format(x)) for x in xrange(5)]
pprint(users, indent=4)

for x in xrange(5):
    i = randint(2,6) 
    if i in users:
        print("User already exists: {}".format(i))
    else:
        print("{} is not in users list. Creating new user with id: {}".format(i, i))
        users.append(User(i, 'new_user{}'.format(i)))
pprint(users, indent=4)
```

This creates output similar to this:

```
[   0 => name_0, 
    1 => name_1, 
    2 => name_2, 
    3 => name_3, 
    4 => name_4]
6 is not in users list. Creating new user with id: 6
6 is not in users list. Creating new user with id: 6
6 is not in users list. Creating new user with id: 6
3 is not in users list. Creating new user with id: 3
3 is not in users list. Creating new user with id: 3
[   0 => name_0,
    1 => name_1,
    2 => name_2,
    3 => name_3,
    4 => name_4,
    6 => new_user6,
    6 => new_user6,
    6 => new_user6,
    3 => new_user3,
    3 => new_user3]
```

The issue is that the user with id `6` should have only been created 1 time, because it wasn't created already. The second and third time that `6` was attempted, it should have failed. The user would id `3` shouldn't have been recreated at all because it was part of the initialization of the `users` variable.

How do I modify by `__contains__` method to be able to properly utilize `in` when comparing against multiple instances of my class?

Comment: `if any(i in u for u in users)`

Comment: Off topic: are you sure you want to implement `__contains__` for checking IDs? I don't find an expression like `123 in user` very intuitive

Comment: Would you want `'name_1' in user1` to be `True` too?

Comment: @PeterWood, No, it should just be checking the `id`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a misuse of `__contains__`. You would expect to implement `__contains__` on a class like `UserList`.

A better way to do this is to just access the `id` attribute directly in generator expression or list comprehension (rather than using the in operator). eg.

```
class User(object):
    def __init__(self, id=None, name=None):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name

user = User(1, 'name_1')
assert 1 == user.id

user_list = [user, User(2, 'name_2')]
assert any(2 == u.id for u in user_list)
```

Then for your random example, you'd use a set or dictionary to store the ids of the users that already exist.

```
users = [User(x, 'name_{}'.format(x)) for x in xrange(5)]
ids = set(u.id for u in users)

for x in xrange(5):
    i = randint(2,6) 
    if i in ids:
        print("User id already exists: {}".format(i))
    else:
        print("{} is not in users list. Creating new user with id: {}".format(i, i))
        ids.add(i)
        users.append(User(i, 'new_user{}'.format(i)))
```

Answer (score 6):

If `users` is a list of users and you check `if i in users`, then you are not checking `User.__contains__`. You are checking `list.__contains__`. Whatever you do in `User.__contains__` is not going to affect the result of checking if `i` is in a list.

If you want to check if `i` matches any `User` in `users`, you could do:

```
if any(i in u for u in users)
```

Or a bit more clearly:

```
if any(u.id==i for u in users)
```

and avoid using `User.__contains__` at all.

Answer (score 6):

This seems like a case where you really wanted to define `__eq__` to accept comparisons to both other `User` objects and `int`. This would make contains checks for collections of `User`s work automatically, and would make much more sense in general usage than implementing `__contains__` on a non-container type.

```
import sys
from operator import index

class User(object):  # Explicit inheritance from object can be removed for Py3-only code
    def __init__(self, id=None, name=None):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name

    def __eq__(self, item):
        if isinstance(item, User):
            return self.id == item.id and self.name == item.name
        try:
            # Accept any int-like thing
            return self.id == index(item)
        except TypeError:
            return NotImplemented

    # Canonical mirror of __eq__ only needed on Py2; Py3 defines it implicitly
    if sys.version_info < (3,):
        def __ne__(self, other):
            equal = self.__eq__(other)
            return equal if equal is NotImplemented else not equal

    def __hash__(self):
        return self.id
```

Now you can use your type with normal collections (including `set` and `dict` keys) and it can be looked up easily.

```
from operator import attrgetter

# Use set for faster lookup; can sort for display when needed
users = {User(x, 'name_{}'.format(x)) for x in xrange(5)}
pprint(sorted(users, key=attrgetter('id')), indent=4)

for x in xrange(5):
    i = randint(2,6) 
    if i in users:
        print("User already exists: {}".format(i))
    else:
        print("{} is not in users list. Creating new user with id: {}".format(i, i))
        users.add(User(i, 'new_user{}'.format(i)))
pprint(sorted(users, key=attrgetter('id')), indent=4)
```

Comment: Won't this fail on the `user = {...}` line because there isn't a `__getitem__` defined?

Comment: @NewGuy: Why would it need `__getitem__`? That's a special method for sequences and mappings; `User` is neither. For an object to be a member of a `set` (which is what the braces do, it's now a set comprehension instead of a list comprehension), it must define `__eq__` and `__hash__`; it doesn't need `__getitem__` unless you're trying to make your own `list`- or `dict`-like class.